# Hide CfnOutput values in CDK console log

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I'm using CfnOutout in my TypeScript CDK code and would like to output secret values, but at the same time hide them from the console log.
This is how I use them:

```
const accessKey = new CfnAccessKey(this, 'testUserKey', {
  userName: testUser.userName,
});

const accessKeyId = new CfnOutput(this, 'accessKey', { value: accessKey.ref });
const attrSecretAccessKey = new CfnOutput(this, 'secretAccessKey', { value: accessKey.attrSecretAccessKey });
```

Is there a way to stop CDK from showing them in the console logs?
Currently CDK shows them in the log as below:

```
Outputs:
stagingConsulComponents.accessKey = ADGHHBAS26TGDRGV
stagingConsulComponents.secretAccessKey = JKGHDJhdskjhfzhfsdjdafhJHJdd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear there is any way to suppress the output of those values. However, a little `sed` work could get you there:

```
$ cdk deploy ... | sed -E "s/(accessKey) = (.*)$/\1 = masked/" | sed -E "s/(secretAccessKey) = (.*)$/\1 = masked/"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think CDK can make an output "sensitive" and hide from the console, you can use sed as the first answer, and that will solve.
I would recommend, if you can, push these credentials to AWS secret manager and pull them, so in this case, you don't even need to output them and they will never be in plain text:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager-readme.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/get_secrets_manager_value.html